# Jasperserver installation unable to access database

Tags: mysql, installation, database-connection, jasperserver

I am trying to install jasperserver(war) in a CentOS linux machine. It throws up error saying,

```
 Message: [Access denied for user 'jasperdb'@'xx.xx.xx.xx' to database 'mysql']
```

However, when I access mysql via command prompt it works fine. I am able to access via the user jasperdb from same machine where I am trying to install jasperserver.

It is also weird why jasperserver tries to access the database with name 'mysql'? Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The mysql database within mysql is the one where user info is stored.  That is why it is trying to access the mysql database.  I am assuming you have 'jasperdb'@'localhost' in your mysql.user table.  Try making sure that localhost and any other computer names are in your /etc/hosts filled in for 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi - No I don't have mysql in my localhost, it is a in a different machine. I have also made sure that the properies in the default_master.properties have the right credentials and db information.

Comment: have u checked the mysql.user table in the database?  is there any 'jasperdb' users created in the database?   if there is a 'jasperdb'@'localhost', u might be able to copy this user to create 'jasperdb'@'xx.xx.xx.xx'

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the ".war file" installer, I recommend using that. It's a lot easier to troubleshoot than the installer that bundles in Tomcat and PostgreSQL.

If you are using that, then you should find the credentials that you have set in default_master.properties. That includes both the user name and the database name. Run `ant clean-config` to make sure you aren't picking up any old settings.